# How to create a subset of nested attibutes with Ruby on Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

My application is a knowledge base describing business rules in several languages. Translations of name and description are designed as nested attributes. They are not present in the master table, only in the translations table:

```
  id            :integer          not null, primary key
  field_name    :string(30)       not null
  language      :string(2)        not null
  translation   :text
  created_at    :datetime         not null
  updated_at    :datetime         not null
```

Business rules can have many translations, as declare in the model:

```
  has_many :name_translations, -> { where("field_name='name'") }, class_name: 'Translation'
  has_many :description_translations, -> { where("field_name='description'") }, class_name: 'Translation'
```

At creation, I initialise these translations in the business rules controller:

```
  def new
    @business_rule = BusinessRule.new
    @business_rule.name_translations.build(language: user_language, field_name: 'name')
    @business_rule.name_translations.build(language: user_language, field_name: 'description')
  end
```

In the _form.html.rb, I want to display only the translation for current user's language. Of course, at rule's creation, there is only one language available, but as I use the same form for update, I need to filter nested translations and keep only current user's language:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 text-right"> <%= t('Name')%>:
    </div>
    <%= f.fields_for :name_translations, @business_rule.name_translations.where('language=?', user_language) do |naming| %>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <%= naming.text_field :translation, :class => "col-md-10" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <%= naming.hidden_field :field_name, :value => 'name' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <%= naming.hidden_field :language, :value => user_language %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

This works fine for editing an existing business rule. But for business rule creation, the nested field do not show.

If I remove the

> @business_rule.name_translations.where('language=?', user_language)

expression, the input filed is displayed. But this does not fit editing requirement because all translations are shown as well.

I suspect that this expression queries the nested attributes from the database, and not the ones initialised by the **new** method in the controller.

Is there a way to avoid this, or to filter the **:name_translations** passed to the **fields_for** method ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't need to filter the **:name_translations** for `new` action. So, in the form you can use `persisted?` to check if the record exists:

```
<%= f.fields_for :name_translations, @business_rule.name_translations.where('language=?', user_language) if @business_rule.persisted? do |naming| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Thanks to this, you are able to filter nested attributes only for existed records.

Comment: I had to enclose the condition in parenthesis to have it working: (@business_rule.name_translations.where('language=?', user_language) if @business_rule.persisted?) but this solved the issue. Thanks!